# Php upload page don't upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I created a simple php page to upload a file but, it does not work. I the message ok but if I enter the folder "prova" there is nothing...
The folder is set to 777 here there is the code

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
    <form action="importazione.php?a=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Aggiorna" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    $messaggio= $_GET['a'];
    define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/home/me/Scrivania/prova");
    if ($messaggio == 1)
    {
        $allowedExts = array("txt");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ( $temp[1] == "txt") {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            } 
            else {
                if(isset($_FILES['file']))
                {
                    $file = $_FILES['file'];
                    if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK and is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']))
                    {
                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$file['name']);
                        echo "OK";
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: It will *always* say ok. You don't [check for errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) so that line of code will always be reached.

Comment: You have `UPLOAD_DIR.$file['name']`, which probably evaluates to something like `/home/me/Scrivania/provafilename.txt` (note the missing slash). Also, does the PHP user have rights to this directory?

Comment: now i print echo $file['error'];
and I obtain "0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/home/me/Scrivania/prova");
```

To this:

```
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/home/me/Scrivania/prova/");
```

Tested your script on my server and works fine, just needed that extra slash on the end, because the url to where the file is to be uploaded to is translates to:

/home/me/Scrivania/provafile.txt

when it should be

/home/me/Scrivania/prova/file.txt

-- Edit --

Also if you intend on using the ext array change the if statement to the following:

```
if ( in_array($temp[1], $allowedExts) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$file['name']);
```

to this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: The OP has `$file = $_FILES['file'];` right above that line.

Comment: he has used variable $file = $_FILES['file'];

Comment: @Jared Farrish & PravinS: You are right it did work in my system with little alteration. I have edited the code accordingly.